# How to Serve Files from Outside Public Directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Whenever I try to serve content (via send_file or as the src of an iframe) from a directory outside of 'public' via the asset's relative or absolute path I get an error stating either the asset could not be found or 'c' (as in C:) is not a valid protocol. Does anyone know why I'm facing these problems and how to solve them without using symlink?

Thanks.

Comment: You can simply share files using your web server instead of application server.  Just put your files in proper directory and tune HTTP server.  But your application also should know where those assets are located in order to redirect user.

Comment: @taro, the reason for keeping files out of the public directory is because they are sensitive files that can only be given to (some) authenticated users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess, as I don't use Windows for anything other than browser testing.

Instead of creating the string for the file path (e.g. `send_file "C:\sites\this_one\secure_files\here.pdf"`) use the File class to build the path (e.g. `send_file File.join(Rails.root, 'secure_files', 'here.pdf')`).